# How to substitute text from a line in bash

Tags: sed

I have txt file like this one:

```
Linux Mint 17   
Ubuntu 14.04   
Debian GNU/Linux 7.0   
Mageia 4   
Fedora 20   
openSUSE 13.1   
Arch Linux   
CentOS 7.0-1406  
PCLinuxOS 2014.07   
Slackware Linux 14.1   
FreeBSD
```

I need to take version numbers and put it to the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whit `awk` you can do some like this:

```
awk '$NF~/[0-9\.]+/ {f=$NF;$NF="";$0=f FS$0}1' file
17 Linux Mint
14.04 Ubuntu
7.0 Debian GNU/Linux
4 Mageia
20 Fedora
13.1 openSUSE
Arch Linux
7.0-1406 CentOS
2014.07 PCLinuxOS
14.1 Slackware Linux
FreeBSD
```

If last field contain any number, move it to front position.